# Implement a promise once a tween has finished animating

Tags: javascript, promise, gsap

I am using Tween to make an animation, and once that animation has completed I want to trigger another action to set the `src` of an iframe.

I know i need to use promises, but I am not 100% sure how to implement it in this case, and have been trying for quite sometime now. It works with the following code

```
Tween.to('#slideshow', 1, {
    top: '50%'
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $('.video-one').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/testOne');
    $('.video-one').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/testOne');
  }, 800)
```

**BUT** when I try the following it doesn't work

```
Tween.to('#slideshow', 1, {
    top: '50%'
}).done(function(){
     $('.video-one').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/testOne');
     $('.video-one').attr('src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/testOne');
});
```

Comment: It's `then` not `done`

Comment: There are multiple libraries called "tween". Which are you using? Please link it.

Comment: its this one http://greensock.com/gsap  `done` doesn't work in this case `build.js:353 Uncaught TypeError: Tween.to(...).then is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I'm seeing in the [User Guide](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md), Tween.js doesn't support Promises. Instead you have to use the callbacks that they specify. In this case I'm guessing `onComplete` is what you're looking for:

```
Tween.to('#slideshow', 1, {
  top: '50%'
}).onComplete(function() {
  // Code goes here
});
```

Comment: I am using it with another framework where i need to call a done function in the onComplete. Code looks like this `Tween.to($('.section-five'), 1, { ease:Back.easeOut,onComplete: done });` This is the Tween I am using  greensock.com/gsap

Comment: ignore me, i figured it out

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this kind of scenario is provided for (maybe inadvertently) by the guys at TweenLite's creators GreenSock.

Bundled with TweenLite in their GSAP download is [jquery.gsap.js](http://greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin#), a jQuery plugin, which they introduce as follows :

> Good news for anyone using jQuery.animate() - the new jquery.gsap.js plugin allows you to have GSAP take control under the hood so that your animations perform better; no need to change any of your code. Plus GSAP adds numerous capabilities, allowing you to tween colors, 2D transforms (rotation, scaleX, scaleY, skewX, skewY, x, y), 3D transforms (rotationX, rotationY, z, perspective), backgroundPosition, boxShadow, and lots more. You can even animate to a different className!

With jquery.gsap.js installed, `jQuery().animate()` will animate using TweenLite, and still allow jQuery's `.promise()` to be chained, giving you a promise of completion.

First install jQuery, TweenMax (or TweenLite and its CSS plugin) and the jquery.gsap.js plugin :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-x.y.z.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/TweenMax.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.gsap.js"></script>
```

Now, you can write a standard jQuery `.animate()` with the benefits of TweenMax/TweenLite, and still return a jQuery promise :

```js
function doAnimation() {
    return $("#myID").animate({
        backgroundColor: "#FF0000", // color animation is not provided by raw jQuery.
        width: "50%",
        top: "100px",
        ease: Power2.easeInOut // this is a GSAP easing function
    }).promise();
}

doAnimation().then(function() {
    console.log('animation complete');
});
```